# Google Charts API and auto-refresh multiple gauges from json data

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-visualization

I'm struggling to find a solution to how to get multiple gauges to "auto update" via ajax.  I'm expecting 3 gauges to appear (Gauge1, Gauge2, and Gauge3) and as per documentation, each is a column with a single numeric value.  I've seen the PHP MySQL Google Chart JSON - Complete Example from this site and read the google documentation, but none really help me troubleshoot what's happening here.  I'm not getting anything into the data variable and I'm not getting any error messages other than "Data Table Not Set".  Here's the code:

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
    var data;
    var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 190,
        redFrom: 7,
        redTo: 10,
        greenFrom: 0,
        greenTo: 5,
        yellowFrom: 5,
        yellowTo: 7,
        minorTicks: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        majorTicks: ["",""],
        animation: {
            duration: 100
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gaugediv'));

    function refreshData () {
        //alert("refreshing");
        var json = $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php', 
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false
        }).responseText;
        alert(json); //shows good data
        data = google.visualization.DataTable(json);
        alert("did I make it here?");  // nope. Doesn't alert.   
        chart.draw(data, options);
        //setInterval(refreshData, 3000);
    }

    refreshData();
    //setInterval(refreshData, 3000);
}
```

Here's what I get from data.php

```
{
  cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'Gauge1', type: 'number'},
         {id: 'B', label: 'Gauge2', type: 'number'},
         {id: 'C', label: 'Gauge3', type: 'number'}
  ],
  rows: [{c:[{v: '8'},
             {v: '6'},
             {v: '4'}
        ]}
  ]
}";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the `new` keyword is missing when trying to create the `DataTable`
everything else looks ok...

`data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['gauge'],
  callback: drawChart
});

function drawChart() {
  var json = {
    cols: [
      {id: 'A', label: 'Gauge1', type: 'number'},
      {id: 'B', label: 'Gauge2', type: 'number'},
      {id: 'C', label: 'Gauge3', type: 'number'}
    ],
    rows: [
      {c:[
        {v: '8'},
        {v: '6'},
        {v: '4'}
      ]}
    ]
  };

  // be sure to use the 'new' keyword here...
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gaugediv'));
  var options = {
    width: 600,
    height: 190,
    redFrom: 7,
    redTo: 10,
    greenFrom: 0,
    greenTo: 5,
    yellowFrom: 5,
    yellowTo: 7,
    minorTicks: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    majorTicks: ["",""],
    animation: {
      duration: 100
    }
  };
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="gaugediv"></div>
```

Comment: That seemed to solve one of two issues.  The chart appears, but I see you put the json in a var.  I tried to update it with my ajax call again, but the chart wouldn't display and I couldn't find any errors.  I updated to this:  `var json = $.getJSON("data.php");
 alert(json); //should be object - this is now object` and I get an object now, but no chart display.